# Using libcurl with libevent

Tags: c, asynchronous, libcurl, nonblocking, libevent

Can anyone show (through code) or explain to me how I might use libevent and curl together in a c program? I'm trying to write a high-performance non-blocking data monitor which needs to upload data to a CouchDB instance. I'm familiar with both libevent and curl, but merging curl_multi with libevent has me stumped for some reason. I do not understand the program flow of the offical [libcurl example](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/hiperfifo.html) - can anyone point me to, or supply, a simpler example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key is really the [curl_multi_socket_action](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_multi_socket_action.html)() function that should be used as soon as your event library says there's something on a socket to deal with. Event-based libcurl is more complex than "plain" libcurl so doing a very easy example is not that straight forward.

Comment: when I call `curl_multi_socket_action()` telling it either to read or write, does it use the read/write callback functions that were set up using `curl_easy_setopt()`? If not, how does it perform the read/write?

Comment: Yes, it will use the callbacks for reading/writing as you have setup.

Comment: Ah, alright, that make this a little clearer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

One exotic way to use `curl` with `libevent` is in a [coroutine](https://github.com/user1095108/cr2/blob/master/curldemo.cpp).